# Почему алгоритм O(n^3)?

Tags: алгоритм, асимптотика

Почему алгоритм O(n^3)?

```
def a(N):
    k = 0
    for i in range (N**2):
        for j in range (N//2):
            print(k)
            k += 1
```

Comment: Первый цикл сколько оборотов делает? А второй? А перемножить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
for i in range(N**2):
```

Итого примерно N<sup>2</sup> раз выполнить

```py
for j in range(N//2):
```

нечто, что выполняется примерно N/2 раза, т.е. всего N<sup>3</sup>/2 раз сделать

```py
print(k)
k += 1
```

что выполняется за константное время. Ну, а при определении O(...) все константы отбрасываются. Итак, получаем O(N<sup>3</sup>)...

Comment: Кажется, вы недавно подобное уже объясняли тому же человеку ;)

Comment: Повторение - мать ученья.

Comment: Если есть в дебри, то `+= 1` - логарифм (а могла бы быть амортизированная константа), а `print` - квадрат логарифма. В итоге *O(N^3 logN)*.

Comment: @MBo Фиг его знает, запоминаю только отдельных пользователей. Вас, например — но не за вопросы, а за ответы :) Как и отдельные вопросы, которые интересны. Или крайне раздражают (значит, ответил уже с десяток раз).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тут ничего насчет k не говорится, считаю, что это просто целое число, нет?

Comment: Да, k - целое число скорее всего.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда откуда логарифм? Чисто из того, что N может быть ну очень большое, и простая процессорная арифметика уже не пройдет? Но ведь O() абстрагируется от машинной архитектуры :)

Comment: Если `N` не лезет в машинное слово, то появляется логарифм. *O* может быть абстрагировано от этого, если ввести ограничения на *N*. Обычно так и делают: N < 2^64. И никакого логарифма не упоминают. Но если хочется выпендриться, то ...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я это и имел в виду. Но формально O-обозначения архитектуру игнорируют, так?

Comment: Да, на практике и в теории игнорируют. Но честно говоря неограниченное целое в Питоне и ограниченное целое в С++ - это уже не архитектурная разница.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну хорошо, не архитектуру, а особенности реализации :)

Comment: Можно игнорировать, можно учитывать. Обе модели имеют право на применение. Решает практика. Обычно практика решает не обращать внимания на логарифм.